# Java app working when running spring boot but not with Apache

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I created an app using https://start.spring.io/ so when I run `./mvnw spring-boot:run`  the apps work great. But then in order to be able to debug my app (as I always did with others) I select "Debug On Server" and the server compile successfully with the message `INFORMACIÓN: Server startup in 4288 ms`

But when I try to access to the app I get 404 error.

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.domain.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>app</name>
    <description>app</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thhis is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/api/products",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;

    @GetMapping("")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public String getAllProducts() {
        return this.productService.initCrawler();
    }
}
```

And the URL I'm pointing is:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/api/products
```

And the response is `HTTP 404`

Also eclipse after the build open the explorer in `http://localhost:8080/app` but it gets also 404.

When running directly with `./mvnw spring-boot:run` the URL that works fine is http://localhost:8080/api/products which is not working neither when I use `Run as Server`

And in the logs doesn't say anything...

Comment: You probably need to add more details to the question before it is down voted. Example , url that was successful and not successful , error logs if any , controller class etc

Comment: Where is the "with Apache" here?

Comment: When I select run on server, it serve the app using eclipse apache

Comment: You need to learn about the concept of a "servlet container" and then never use it. Don't "run on server" (which means in an external container); just run like a regular command-line application and let Spring manage the Web connector for you.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- so how can I debug the code using the command line?

Comment: Are you in Eclipse? Just use "Debug as..." and you'll have Java Application as an option, and Spring Boot App if you have the Spring tools installed (not necessary, but gives you some extra diagnostics). "Server" here specifically means _external servlet container_, which is not what you want.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- thanks! that works! one question, this way there isn't any hot reload feature, right?

Comment: DevTools should work fine. JRebel is pricey but worthwhile if you're doing this programming full-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood your question this way. You have created a spring boot application from Spring Initializr and  the application run successfully from command line but not when you are trying to deployed in server and start the server in debug mode.

You should know that Spring Initializr created a spring boot application which is  `stand-alone`, production-grade Spring based Applications that you can "just run". With stand-alone meaning the the server is incorporated as dependency in spring boot app and you don't need to deployed in server.

If you want to deploy in server , you need to make  Spring Boot Application @SpringBootApplication class extend the SpringBootServletInitializer class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

You should specify in maven the main class that is going to run and change the packaging from jar to war.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
<start-class>com.tutorialspoint.demo.DemoApplication</start-class>
```

For more information how to make you spring boot application to be deployed in server, check the link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_tomcat_deployment.htm

If you don't need the application to run on the server , you just want to debug the code. I would suggest to use eclipse or intellij. You  include spring boot dashboard in perspective and start the spring boot application in debug mode. Check this link to understand how to include and use spring boot dashboard : https://medium.com/danielpadua/java-spring-boot-eclipse-744454468670

Comment: Great, this was the answer I was looking for. One last question, at the end, I will need this app to be in a server (in production) so, with mvn install I will get the war to install in the server if I just use spring boot tool here?

Comment: With mvn install what you do is you package the project and put it in your maven  local repository .m2 folder.  If you need this app to be deployed in server you need to do the modification that i explained in the answer. And after that run mvn clean install. Go to your local repository home/@user/.m2 is hidden folder. Find the war  that is generated from mvn clean install and copy it to the server.

Comment: Do you have any other question?

Comment: If you can please tell my which is the other alternative to not have to deploy this in a server for production? How can I serve my app whitout that?

Comment: So I can decide which option is better for me

Comment: If  you want just to deploy the application. You run mvn clean install. This is going to package the application in jar file and installed it in your local repository that is located home/user/.m2 folder. You take the jar file  and place in  your production machine(server). You don't need a tomcat or any other  server. You can just run it as normal jar.  ```$ jar -xf myapp.jar```

Comment: Here it is a link providing more information on how to deploy a spring boot app https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html

Comment: If this information has been helpful , I would appreciate vote up or accepted answers. You would help me a lot by giving some privileges points. Regards, Rando. Feel free to ask back if you have something you don't understand.